# Are 5V Illuminated Rocker Switches common or is it common practice to add external resistor to LED path?

Tags: led, resistors, switches

I am looking to add a rocker switch to a design and looking to power the circuits using 5VDC. I would like the rocker switch to have a built-in LED indicator and to my surprise I have been having trouble getting a clear answer on whether or not I can obtain a switch that will work at 5V and have the LED's resistor value be tuned to that so that it is sufficiently bright. Am I missing something?

**My specific questions would be:**

1. It is the common practice to put the resistor in series with your LED's patht to ground for rocker switches? Is it just assumed this is what you do?
2. If the above is not true, are 5V switches not common? I see a lot of illuminated switches rated at 12VDC.

A part I am looking at is the 54-645 switch from NTE:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/54-645/11650188

Its lamp voltage is 2V @ 20 mA. By my calculations, a series 150 ohm resistor would be appropriate for this configuration. To me, it looks like the resistor is usually added inside the switch and cannot be changed but a Digikey rep thought differently and the NTE rep said, "The LED in the 54-645 is rated at 2V, 20mA. Running with a higher voltage could cause the LED to run hot, or burn out completely, and is NOT RECOMMENDED."
I am not sure how you read that but unless I am missing a screw today it does not directly answer the question of whether the resist is internal or external. The datasheet also seems to indicate a resistor is in series.

I appreciate any info you all can offer.
[image: 54-645]

Comment: Add external R to suit.

Comment: The manufacturer knows that the switch may get operated in various systems with various voltages available, so it would limit his market if he put a resistor in there for a specific voltage. The same goes for different illumination conditions. It's best if he leaves the choice of resistor up to you, to add externally. He's specified the lightsource as a LED dropping 2 V at 20 mA, which is quite enough to know.

Comment: @Neil_UK I would have thought this too, I suppose I just was looking for a more direct confirmation from the manufacturer that that was their intention. A rep directly told me in email both the LED rating information and not to run at a higher voltage and that I couldn’t order variations with different resistor values, which made it sound to me like there was a resistor inside. In any case, I should have one in hand soon enough to test.

Comment: The fact that he told you not to run the LED at a higher voltage confirms he has no idea what he's talking about. His expertise is BS'ing on the telephone, not designing LED drivers. If it says '2V', it's a plain LED, and you need to provide a current, not a voltage to drive it. To test it, apply various low currents <20 mA with a large series resistor, and measure the voltage drop across the LED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 V 20 mA sounds like a bare red LED - you would need to add an external resistor to operate it from 5 V.

You may adjust the resistor value to give the desired brightness.  LEDs are not fussy about current, as long as you keep under their rated maximum current.  I find most LEDs are bright enough to use as indicators when operated at 10 mA or less.

Comment: Yep, it works great with a resistor in series.